# CSS sprite animation using step with sprite sheet that is not linear not stepping

Tags: html, css

I have a spritesheet and I want to use step() to animate it.

All the css examples I can find use a sprite sheet that is 1xnumFrames
my sprite sheet is 3x5.  I am looking for a pure css solution.

I tried the following but I can see the steps in between instead of stepping it slides from one to the other.

css

```
@-webkit-keyframes crystal-wave {
0.0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
7.14286% {background-position: -270px 0px;}
14.28571% {background-position: -540px 0px;}
21.42857% {background-position: 0px -314px;}
28.57143% {background-position: -270px -314px;}
35.71429% {background-position: -540px -314px;}
42.85714% {background-position: 0px -628px;}
50.0% {background-position: -270px -628px;}
57.14286% {background-position: -540px -628px;}
64.28571% {background-position: 0px -942px;}
71.42857% {background-position: -270px -942px;}
78.57143% {background-position: -540px -942px;}
85.71429% {background-position: 0px -1256px;}
92.85714% {background-position: -270px -1256px;}
100.0% {background-position: -540px -1256px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes crystal-wave {
0.0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
7.14286% {background-position: -270px 0px;}
14.28571% {background-position: -540px 0px;}
21.42857% {background-position: 0px -314px;}
28.57143% {background-position: -270px -314px;}
35.71429% {background-position: -540px -314px;}
42.85714% {background-position: 0px -628px;}
50.0% {background-position: -270px -628px;}
57.14286% {background-position: -540px -628px;}
64.28571% {background-position: 0px -942px;}
71.42857% {background-position: -270px -942px;}
78.57143% {background-position: -540px -942px;}
85.71429% {background-position: 0px -1256px;}
92.85714% {background-position: -270px -1256px;}
100.0% {background-position: -540px -1256px;}
}
@-o-keyframes crystal-wave {
0.0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
7.14286% {background-position: -270px 0px;}
14.28571% {background-position: -540px 0px;}
21.42857% {background-position: 0px -314px;}
28.57143% {background-position: -270px -314px;}
35.71429% {background-position: -540px -314px;}
42.85714% {background-position: 0px -628px;}
50.0% {background-position: -270px -628px;}
57.14286% {background-position: -540px -628px;}
64.28571% {background-position: 0px -942px;}
71.42857% {background-position: -270px -942px;}
78.57143% {background-position: -540px -942px;}
85.71429% {background-position: 0px -1256px;}
92.85714% {background-position: -270px -1256px;}
100.0% {background-position: -540px -1256px;}
}
@keyframes crystal-wave {
0.0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
7.14286% {background-position: -270px 0px;}
14.28571% {background-position: -540px 0px;}
21.42857% {background-position: 0px -314px;}
28.57143% {background-position: -270px -314px;}
35.71429% {background-position: -540px -314px;}
42.85714% {background-position: 0px -628px;}
50.0% {background-position: -270px -628px;}
57.14286% {background-position: -540px -628px;}
64.28571% {background-position: 0px -942px;}
71.42857% {background-position: -270px -942px;}
78.57143% {background-position: -540px -942px;}
85.71429% {background-position: 0px -1256px;}
92.85714% {background-position: -270px -1256px;}
100.0% {background-position: -540px -1256px;}
}

.crystal-waving {
/*width:14.94%;
height:23.31%;
left:22.66%;
top:37.24%;*/
border: solid thin red;
background: url("cc.png") no-repeat left top;
-webkit-animation: crystal-wave 5s steps(15) infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
-moz-animation:    crystal-wave 5s steps(15) infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
-o-animation:      crystal-wave 5s steps(15) infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
animation:         crystal-wave 5s steps(15) infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

html

```
<div class="crystal-waving" style="width:276px; height:372px;"></div>
```

[image: sprite map]

Here is the texture atlas

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<TextureAtlas imagePath="button_cc.png">
<!-- Created with Adobe Flash CS6 version 12.0.2.529 -->
<!-- http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html -->
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0000" x="0" y="0" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0001" x="270" y="0" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0002" x="540" y="0" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0003" x="0" y="314" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0004" x="270" y="314" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0005" x="540" y="314" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0006" x="0" y="628" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0007" x="270" y="628" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0008" x="540" y="628" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0009" x="0" y="942" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0010" x="270" y="942" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0011" x="540" y="942" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0012" x="0" y="1256" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0013" x="270" y="1256" width="270" height="314"/>
<SubTexture name="Button_CC0014" x="540" y="1256" width="270" height="314"/>
</TextureAtlas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're going to accomplish this with `step()`. Normally I've seen `step` animations specified using a start and end condition, and letting `step` take care of the tweening for you. Since you're specifying the tweening conditions in your keyframes, you'd have to make sure the math matches exactly, which is going to be impossible (100/14 doesn't give you an evenly divisible number).

I'd really explore ways you might be able to use a linear sprite sheet. If your workflow doesn't support it out of the box, perhaps you could restructure it in "post" using a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to slice the 2D image and recompose it into a linear one.

Finally, if you're unable to use linear sprite sheet at all, the only solution I can think of is to specify "boundary" keyframes that bracket your actual transition points, such that the animation happens in a very short period of time:

```
0.0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
7.14285% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
7.14286% {background-position: -270px 0px;}
14.28570% {background-position: -270px 0px;}
14.28571% {background-position: -540px 0px;}
...
etc.
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kihuwo/1/edit)**

Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking of this but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution. Can you see if there is something wrong in my code because it doesn't seem to be stepping at all. it is as if I am not using step.

Comment: I tried the boundary frames but I still can't make it work. looks like I'll have to make it linear. I'll wait and see if anyone else chimes in but this looks like the solution.

Comment: What's wrong with your code is that you're mixing `step` with specified keyframes other than `0%` and `100%`. You can't really make the math work to completely specify the keyframe at exactly 1/14th intervals. If you change your animation to have a number of frames evenly divisible into 100, you could try composing that way, but even then, I'm not sure what would happen.

Comment: I tried that with the standard example but even with that one I couldn't get it to work and it as 10 frames.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbpgbL

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30635504/2225439

Or

[Refer this](https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/sprite-sheet-animation-using-html-css-9091bebd4eeb)

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Sprite-Sheet Animation
        </title>
        <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”main.css”>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=”animatedDiv”></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.animatedDiv {
    width: 820px;
    height: 312px;
    background-image: url("https://cf.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/animation-strips/hero-intro-bg-vflR5rUow.jpg");
    -webkit-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -moz-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -ms-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -o-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the sprite sheet is not linear. The sprite sheet in this example is linear. If you look at my sprite sheet it is 3 x 5 this uses a 1 x 48.