# How can I create an Animated Button with a Sprite Sheet using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to create an animated button using a sprite sheet. The animation should play on hover and then on mouseout the animation should finish and then stop.

How can I go about doing this? I have tried setting the background of a div and controlling the background position through hover events. I can get the background position to set itself properly but each change goes so fast it might as well be instant and so the animation does not show itself.

Any suggestions would be helpful. After a lot of searching with no luck I am not sure what else to try.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best advice would be to use a CSS3.
pretty easy no need for javascript:

take a look at this for example:

```
http://codeitdown.com/css-sprite-animations/
```

example here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/drukaman/ued7mLha/1/
```

Comment: Thank but I run into the same problem I have with other solutions. The animation doesn't finish before going to the still frame. I would like the animation, on mouseout, to finish before it goes back to the still frame. I should have added that into the title but it was a bit long. Or am I missing something and it could be easily possible?

Comment: in that case as an alternative you could pick canvas sprite as a solution.. there's simple demos and plugins  for that as well... that would save you tons of work. here's one of the many : http://darsa.in/motio/

Answer (score 2):

from the Referance : https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/sprite-sheet-animation-using-html-css-9091bebd4eeb

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Sprite-Sheet Animation
        </title>
        <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”main.css”>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=”animatedDiv”></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.animatedDiv {
    width: 820px;
    height: 312px;
    background-image: url("https://cf.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/animation-strips/hero-intro-bg-vflR5rUow.jpg");
    -webkit-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -moz-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -ms-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -o-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
```

for Detailed explanation follow the [link](https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/sprite-sheet-animation-using-html-css-9091bebd4eeb).